# Show/Hide React component after a transition/animation

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I've got a React component which needs to be shown/hidden.  I understand how to do that generally, however, in my case, theres a grow/shrink animation that should occur before the show/hide action.  What's the best (easiest?) way to do that without adding additional packages (like React Spring) ??

The show/collapse transition works fine, I simply want the result to be like `return null` after the collapse=true transition is done, and, of course, the reverse when collapse=false

========== MyClass.scss ==========

```
@use 'utils/animation';

.my-class {
  transition: height animation.duration(500ms) animation.$default-timing-function;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  height: 9rem;
  overflow: hidden;

  margin-inline-start: 0;
  margin-inline-end: 0;
  padding-inline-start: 0;
  padding-inline-end: 0;
}

.my-class-collapsed {
  height: 0;
}
```

========== MyClass.tsx ==========

```
export const myClass = ({
  items,
  collapsed = false,

  className,
  style,

  ...tcProps
}: MyProps) => {

  return (
    <div
      id="Container"
      className={cx(cn.myClass, collapsed && cn.myClassCollapsed, className)}
      style={{ ...tokens, ...style }}
      role="presentation"
    >
    <ClassChildren {...tcProps} style={{ width: '100%' }}>
      {supplyChildren()}
    </ClassChildren>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: read This [5 Ways to animate a React app](https://medium.com/hackernoon/5-ways-to-animate-a-reactjs-app-in-2019-56eb9af6e3bf)

Comment: Thanx.  I'm essentially doing the transition method now.  What I need is additionally for the hidden DIV to essentially be removed from the DOM at the end of the transition, so it doesn't get keyboard or other focus event.  I know I could change the tabstop, but I want to see if it can be removed after transtion on hide and readded before transition on show

Comment: Well show US the code u wrote  so we could help

Comment: code snippets added

Comment: You should know that when working with design issue, a runnable example that display the issue is the easiest to work with.